# Is there a way to change the box plot color where data are significant in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

My data are as follows:

```html
df1<-read.table(text = "time type
12  B88
19  B44
18  B44
13  B88
17  B44",header=TRUE)
```

I can use the following codes to get my plot:

```html
ggplot(df1,aes(type,time)) + geom_boxplot(fill="green")+
  
    stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")
```

I want to get a different colour, let's say blue,  for the box which has a high medium when the P-value is less than 0.05%. Can we do it?
**NOTE:** I am not interested in running ttest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
ggplot(df1,aes(type,time)) + geom_boxplot(fill="green") +
stat_compare_means(method = "t.test") -> p #save your plot as p
build <- ggplot_build(p) # build plot
build$data[[1]][,"fill"] <- ifelse(build$data[[2]][1,"p.format"] < 0.05, list(c("blue","green")),list(rep("green",2))) # changes fill to blue if p value is < 0.05
plot(ggplot_gtable(build)) # plot new formatted graph
```

Comment: @User20100, have you try the solution provided by e.matt ? If it is not working, maybe you can provide a better reproducible example with a t.test p value below 0.05.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant way of doing it but you can calculate the p value outside `ggplot2` and using an `ifelse` statement, attribute a color pattern you can call using `scale_fill_identity`.

Here an example using a dummy example:

```r
df <- data.frame(Xval = rep(c("A","B"),each = 50),
                 Yval = c(sample(1:50,50), sample(50:100,50)))
```

I used `dplyr` pipe sequence here but you cna do that pretty easily in `base r`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% mutate(pval = t.test(Yval~Xval)$p.value) %>%
  group_by(Xval) %>% mutate(Mean = mean(Yval)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Color = ifelse(pval < 0.05 & Mean == max(Mean), "blue","green")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Xval, y = Yval, fill = Color))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")+
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

---

Using your example:

```r
df1 %>% mutate(pval = t.test(time~type)$p.value) %>%
  group_by(type) %>% mutate(Mean = mean(time)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Color = ifelse(pval < 0.05 & Mean == max(Mean), "blue","green")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = time, fill = Color))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")+
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am NOT  interested in running t.test again sorry. It does not work for me

Comment: So, clarify your question in first place